# Dovecot, Courier, Postfix Differences

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, courier

[This question might be against SO guidelines - too vague - too subjective. I have however failed to find an answer]

Like this: [Dovecot vs Courier vs Cyrus](https://serverfault.com/questions/103639/dovecot-vs-courier-vs-cyrus)

What is the difference between Postfix, Dovecot, Courier? Many tutorials require all three for a working email server stack, but wikipedia:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Comparison_of_mail_servers

Seems to state that they all perform a similar function (Especially courier and dovecot).

EDIT:

[Is Dovecot required for mail server like Exim or Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/667843/is-dovecot-required-for-mail-server-like-exim-or-postfix)

Clears things between postfix and dovecot (But not why courier is also suggested for various configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a misconception between MTAs like postfix, sendmail, exim vs mail servers where a client accesses emails stored by the above over common client protocols like imap or Pop3.

You dovecot like others only expose the email stored locally by an MTA to clients for download or sync, in short you need both.

Something else to consider is zimbra and  open365 which are email platforms, which also use postfix under the hood for queuing and delivery with 3rd party mail systems.

Comment: Thank you! Is it safe to say that Dovecot is only a POP3/IMAP frontend, Postfix is an SMTP server/MTA ? What about courier? Where would it be used?

Comment: Instead of dovecot usually

Comment: Try zimbra open-source, very easy and supported by vmware